# What frameworks to use for java Desktop applications

Tags: java, desktop-application, jsr296

I am not familiar with any of the leading frameworks of java but still i managed to develop a desktop application. These days people are talking about spring, strut, hibernate etc.. I want to know how many of kind frameworks exists there and which of them are commonly used for developing a desktop application which involves database as well.

Which of them do you think is a must learn for Desktop application developers. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of those are directly related to desktop applications, although Spring can be used just about anywhere, and Hibernate is app-framework-neutral.

The only real desktop framework player these days, IMO, is [Griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org/).

Comment: I +1'ed this answer, but it could really use more than _one_ framework in response to the OP.  Maybe there really is only one player these days.

Comment: @Jason Other than RCPs (e.g., Eclipse, NetBeans) there aren't too many options in common use. I suppose JavaFX might be on the list, although it doesn't have huge traction either.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you don't really need a framework, take a look at the SWT/JFace Data Binding that is also good to learn for a desktop/database oriented application developer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the NetBeans platform. It is a very sound framework that eases a lot of things - but it does have steep learning curve.

Especially when you know Swing already it's very handy, because you after all it's a Swing framework and plays nicely with any Swing component out there.

Here is a nice little demo showing how to use JPA and the NetBeans platform to create a simple CRUD application:

http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-crud.html

Comment: actually i have used netbeans to develop my first desktop application. I was using JDBC connector for database. I just wanted to know professional way of doing it and update myself with stable frameworks...

Comment: @Deepak: I think you're confusing Netbeans (the IDE) with Netbeans (the platform). Netbeans (the platform) is some kind of framework/library to develop your own desktop applications.

Comment: oh yes when you said netbeans i thought it was IDE and i dont know about netbeans platform. thanks for pointing that out!!